# Server.Execute() or Transfer() in classic ASP to an aspx defined in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, web-config

Server.Execute() or Transfer() to a physical ASPX page from a classic ASP file works with an upgrade to the IIS.

Example:
In test.asp,

```
Server.Execute("/test.aspx")
```

However, if the aspx path is defined in the Web.Config to trigger a handler within a dll, Server.Execute() and Transfer() does not work from a classic ASP file.

Example:
In web.config

```
<add name="test_*" verb="*" path="test.aspx" type="testhttphandler, {fully qualified dll name}">
```

*Please note that there is nothing wrong with how the path is defined in the web.config. I just want to show an example and I apologize for the formatting.

In test.asp

```
Server.Execute("/test.aspx")
```

I get an error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0228 : 80004005'
Server.Execute Error
/test.asp, line 18
The call to Server.Execute failed while loading the page.
```

I understand there are many ways to solve this problem but I would like to understand why that does not work. I personally like to keep things simple as possible with minimum number of files so I explored what I explored above. Let me know if you have any insight.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ASP-Classic (asp.dll) and ASP.Net (aspnet_wp.exe) use different processes, and Server.Execute attempts to use the ASP-Classic interpreter to... err... interpret ASP.Net, which it is not suited to do. Server.Execute attempts to 'execute' the script using the same process that called it: asp.dll.

Server.Transfer to the aspx file is more likely to serve you.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Chris? Does this make sense?

Comment: I also tried same thing with Server.Transfer() and got same result, which only works if aspx page is physical vs. defined in the web.config. Thanks for explaining how it works!

Comment: I guess that means Server.Transfer() is still executed under the classic asp   interpreter.

Comment: No: Server.Transfer passes the original request on to the specified URL to be processed by the driver associated with that file type... it should work just fine to Server.Transfer to the ASPX page.